# Lower/uppercase filenames using bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write a script that runs under bash to lower/uppercase filenames with or without recursion (meaning also changing names in directories inside given directory). Right now it works fine without recursion but I don't know how to implement it with recursion.

I found that most people suggest `find directory -depth | xargs -n 1 rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *` but in my case it starts printing a lot of errors that such files already exist or directory doesn't exist.

What should I change about my code?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]
then
  echo "Missing options!"
  echo "(run $0 -h for help)"
  echo ""
  exit 0
fi

RECURSION="false"

while getopts "hrlu" OPTION; do
  case $OPTION in

    r)
      echo "recursive"
      RECURSION="true"
      ;;
    l)
      echo "lowercase"

      if [[ $RECURSION = "true" ]]
      then
        find $3 -depth | xargs -n 1 rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
      else
        pushd $2
        rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
        popd
      fi
      ;;
    u)
      echo "uppercase"
      if [[ $RECURSION = "true" ]]
      then
        find $3 -depth | xargs -n 1 rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' *
      else
        pushd $2
        rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' *
        popd
      fi
      ;;

    h)
      echo "Usage:"
      echo "$0 -h"
      echo "$0 -r -l <directory> "
      echo "$0 -r -u <directory> "
      echo "$0 -l <directory> "
      echo "$0 -u <directory> "
      echo ""
      echo "   -r     to use recursion"
      echo "   -l     to lowercase all files and directories in given directory"
      echo "   -u     to uppercase all files and directories in given directory"
      echo "   -h     help (this output)"
      exit 0
      ;;

  esac
done
```

Comment: `xargs -n 1 rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' *` ?? No, `xargs -n 1 rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/'` - no `*`. Who suggested `*`? Also there are two versions of `rename `- there is perl rename and util-linux rename. Make sure you have the corrent one. The `y/...` is for perl rename, see `rename --version`.

Comment: ‘_What should I change about my code?_’ [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) has a few suggestions.